# Как распарсить данный объект на java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Существует вот такой json

```
{"Date": "2019-07-24T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousDate": "2019-07-23T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousURL": "\/\/www.cbr-xml-daily.ru\/archive\/2019\/07\/23\/daily_json.js",
    "Timestamp": "2019-07-23T20:00:00+03:00",
    "Valute": {
        "AUD": {
            "ID": "R01010",
            "NumCode": "036",
            "CharCode": "AUD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Австралийский доллар",
            "Value": 44.3355,
            "Previous": 44.3488
        },
        "AZN": {
            "ID": "R01020A",
            "NumCode": "944",
            "CharCode": "AZN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Азербайджанский манат",
            "Value": 36.9976,
            "Previous": 37.1221
        }
}
```

Не понимаю как именно можно распрасить конструкцию "AUD":{object}. 
Желательно с помощью jackson.

Comment: А что вас собственно смущает? Парсите точно так же как и `Valute`

Comment: если вам не сложно, могли бы вы поделиться ответом?

Comment: Если бы я парсил объект на C#, я бы сделал Valute словарем. То есть HashMap.

Comment: Я не понял вопрос.- Вы хотите парсить только "AUD", пропуская (не трогая остальные) объекты JSONa?

Answer (score 0):

можешь через JsonPath

```
ArrayList<String> aud = JsonPath.read($..Valute.AUD);
```

`Valute.AUD.ID` - вернет `R01010`, ну и так далее